# How to freeze the Firefox (and Thunderbird) menu-bars?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, gui, app-menu

Every once in a while I get a call from a user complaining, he can no longer find a certain menu in the browser -- or in Thunderbird -- and I have to painstakingly guide him on re-enabling the menu-panels.

This happens often enough to be annoying, but not often enough for him to still remember, how to do it, by the *next* occurrence...

No one knows, how he manages to hide the menu-panels accidentally...

Hence the question -- perhaps, the menus can be "frozen", so that their removal (hiding) cannot be achieved easily by accident? Some `about:config` nob, perhaps?

Comment: Are you talking about the menu bar?  If so, you may be able to write 1 line of CSS in userChrome.css to always show the menu bar.  I haven't personally tried it, so just writing this as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: If you are talking about the menu bar, it should not require "painstaking guidance" to instruct someone to re-enable it.  In Firefox, simply right-click on any empty area in the tab bar, and select "Menu Bar" from the context menu.  Done.

Comment: This is easy for you and me. Not so easy for the elderly users I'm talking about...

Comment: I hear ya.  Was my guess that you are talking about the menu bar correct?  If so, do you mind editing your question to use the term "menu bar" instead of "menu panel"?